# How to use a button x:Name or something to indicate button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datacontext, sender

I have a problem. I have to do app for college, guitar emulator, my idea was to put each fret as a button, and implement the color change function to understand which fret (button) is clamped (pressed)

```cs
var button = (Button)sender;
_buttonLastPressed = button;
var parent = (Grid)button.Parent;
var index = parent.Children.IndexOf(strip1_1);
var str = Math.Floor((decimal)(index + 1) / 20);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    var element = (Button)parent.Children[i + Convert.ToInt32(str) * 20];
    element.Background = Brushes.White;
}
button.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

This option works well, but the problem arose that I do not know how to get some information from the button in order to use it on what sound to play (so that the program understands which button is pressed). I believe that it was possible to somehow use the DataContext, but I cannot imagine in my head how to do it more competently

*For the tip, there are six strings, I decided to declare each string as grid, and in each grid there are 20 frets (buttons), you can hold down only one of all 20*

XAML:

```xml
<Button x:Name="strip1_1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Height="4" Click="Strip1_Click" BorderBrush="Black"/>
<Button x:Name="strip1_2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Height="4" Click="Strip1_Click" BorderBrush="Black"/>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `Command` property of `Button` and the `ICommand` interface?

Comment: Could you also mention the XAML part of how you use the `<Button/>` object?

Comment: Never heard about it actually...

Comment: @Maaz Oh... All 20 buttons in the grid are tied to one function, which is written in the question, so there are practically no differences between them.
`<Button x:Name="strip1_1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Height="4" Click="Strip1_Click" BorderBrush="Black"/>         <Button x:Name="strip1_2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Height="4" Click="Strip1_Click" BorderBrush="Black"/>`

Comment: I would suggest, as a long term learning feature, reading up about MVVM pattern of programming. Get started here: [MVVM Pattern for Xamarin!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm)

Comment: In the WPF paradigm, buttons should be bound to commands. You can include a command parameter so that the command being invoked knows which fret and or string is actually invoking the command See duplicate for details.

Comment: @Maaz thank you so much for help, appreciate that a lot <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be to use the `Click` property of each button which references a different method.

```
<Button Click="DoSomething_OnClick"/>
```

and in the code-behind:

```
private void DoSomething_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

You could use this to have 20 different methods. This way, you know exactly which button called which method.